# How to match ticker number 0 in a plot with two Y axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, data-visualization

I'm just starting with matplotlib. I'm trying to animate a quantum well simulation and I want to superpose two plots, for some reason I can't match the value 0 on both y axes... Here's a picture of what's wrong:

[image: Picture 1]

I'll attach the code I'm using to animate it as well, but I warn is a bit messy (the problem just happens in the case V0>0 or V0==0) :

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
line,=ax.plot(x,PROB[0,:],"r")
ax2 = ax.twinx()
line2,=ax2.plot(x,V,"b")
fig.text(0.888, 0.84, '$-\infty$')

if V0>0 or V0==0:
    ax2.fill_between(x, V, 0,facecolor='b',alpha=0.1)
    ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0,1),5)

else:
    ax2.fill_between(x, V, V0,facecolor='b',alpha=0.1)
    ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-1,1),5)

if V0 != 0:
    line2.set_ydata(V)

    ax2.set_ylabel("$Potencial(eV)$")
    ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
    ax2.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(which='both', direction='out')
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([0,V0]))
else:
    ax2.set_ylabel("$Potencial(eV)$")
    ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
    ax2.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(which='both', direction='out')
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([0]))
    ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(0,1),5)

ax.set_xlabel("$Posició (nm)$")
ax.set_ylabel("$Probabilitat\;\;|\psi(x)|^2\;\;(nm^{-1})$")
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax.grid(True)
ax.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(which='both', direction='in')
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='both', direction='in')

def animacio(i):
    line.set_ydata(PROB[i,:])
    return line,

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animacio,interval=50, frames=Nt,repeat=False)
nom='Evolució_'
ani.save(str(nom)+'['+str(V0)+','+str(L)+','+str(l)+','+str(xi)+','+str(sigmax)+','+str(T)+']'+'.mp4', writer="ffmpeg")
plt.show()

print('Animation saved as: '+str(nom)+'['+str(V0)+','+str(L)+','+str(l)+','+str(xi)+','+str(sigmax)+','+str(T)+']'+'.mp4')
```

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481990/matplotlib-axis-with-two-scales-shared-origin ?

Comment: This worked out for me! Thank you! :)